# Grabbing the key from the ActionController::Parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**This is my code**

```rb
  def create
    @p_site = PSite.find(params.require(:plan_for).first[0])
    authorize @p_site, :c_s?
    if @p_site.save
      redirect_to :root, notice: "successfully added"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

When I'm running it I get `undefined method 'first' for <ActionController::Parameters:0x00005623c4d56f68>`

My params[:plan_for] looks like this:
`#<ActionController::Parameters {"82"=>"annual"} permitted: false>`

I need to get the value of 82 and find in PSite. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have first permitted my params and then converted it to hash and accessed it by using first[0].

@pp = params.require(:plan_for).permit!.to_h

@p_site = PractitionerSite.find(@pp.first[0])

this will grab my value 82

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Params is a **Hash** here and not an Array. The way a Hash is structured is in **key value pairs**.
For example:

```rb
my_hash = { key: "Some Value" }
mz_hash[:key] #=> "Some Value"
```

So the first thing I am wondering is why you have 82 as the key here? If its an id I would restructure that to be something like this: `{ id: 82, recurrence: "annual" }`

Specifically for your case:

```rb
params[:plan_for]["82"]          #=> "annual"
params.require(:plan_for)["82"]  #=> "annual"

# OR very dirty
params[:plan_for].values.first   #=> "annual"
params[:plan_for].keys.first     #=> "82"
```

You might see how the first two lines above wont work unless "82" is the key for all your params (in which case name it better!) and the latter might be a dirty solution for your code right now but also not something I would recommend.

Check out the documentation for [ruby hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html)

Comment: I think for his case `params[:plan_for].values.first` will return `annual` and `params[:plan_for].keys.first` will return `82`

Comment: good point, :see_no_evil:, fixed